# Set safe-deleting mode for relations table in Sequelize.js

Tags: mysql, orm, sequelize.js

So, assume we have that Sequelize model:

```
 var User = sequelize.define("User", {
        id: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
            allowNull: false,
            primaryKey: true
        },
        password: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(60),
            allowNull: false
        },
        email: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
            allowNull: false,
            unique: true
        },
        firstName: {
            type: DataTypes.STRING(45),
            allowNull: true,
            defaultValue: null
        }
    },
    {
            tableName: 'profiles',
            classMethods: {
                associate: function(models) {
                    User.belongsToMany(User, {through: 'friends', as:'friend'});
                }
            }
        });
```

after calling associate() method, it will create an extra table `friends` with columns `userId`, `friendId`, `createdAt` and `updatedAt`. The case is I need to use this table with safe-deleting mode, in other words, I have to add 'deleted' column somehow. I tried to use `paranoid: true` in belongsToMany's attributes, didn't work. Is there any ways to do it?

Answer (score 2):

Maybe you can create an model/table which name is Friend. And you can set paranoid: true in that model. And when you deleted an User, it keeps User's friend relation was keeping in that model.

I hope it works. :)